# Why doesn't Form->select have a wrapping div?

Tags: php, forms, select, cakephp

I'm wondering why `$this->Form->select()` in CakePHP 2.1 doesn't come with a wrapping `div` and `label`.

Do I have to wrap it by myself like:

```
<?php
     echo '<div><label for="MyModel">MyModel</label>';
     echo $this->Form->select('MyModel', $options, array('empty' => 'choose one'));
     echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's why I never ever use anything else than

```
$this->Form->input();
```

in your case:

```
$this->Form->input('name', array('type'=>'select', 'empty' => 'choose one', 'options'=>$options));
```

no need to ever use select(), text() etc

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('MyModel', array(
        'options' => array(
            'val1' => 'option1',
            'val2' => 'option2'
        )
        ,
        'empty' => __('choose one'),
    ));
?>
```

will achieve the same thing